# BizTalk MLLP receive location, specify localhost instead of server IP address

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, btahl7

I've created a receive location using the HL72x pipeline with MLLP.  I can send hl7 traffic to the server if I set the BizTalk MLLP configuration host property of the receive location to the IP address of the server, but if I set the value to localhost or 127.0.0.1, biztalk will not appear to listen on the respective port.  Using a port scanner, I can only see an open port if the mllp host property of the receive location is set to the IP address of the server.  I don't want to reference the actual ip address of the server, I'd rather us local host, as then if the IP changes, nothing has to be reconfigured.  Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the Host parameter to an IP address of `0.0.0.0`. That will cause the receive location to listen for all inbound traffic on the specified port, regardless of the source's IP address.